# Setting the permissions on all files inside a folder without changing the permissions of the folder itself?

Tags: command-line, permissions, chmod

I have a folder called `my_files`. I want to:

1. set the permissions to allow all users to read, write and execute the folder
2. and set the permissions on all files inside my_files to allow all users to read and write

As a noob having read the manual (`man chmod`), I think that the first is accomplished with:

```
chmod a=rwx my_files
```

I know that the option `-R` applies the permissions recursively, but I don't believe that's what I want for #2. Do I instead navigate my directory to the folder and apply `chmod a=rw`?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the permissions of the folder first, then the contents second (via `/path/to/my_files/*` instead of `/path/to/my_files`) you should be able to accomplish what you're looking to do.



Example:

```
chmod a=rwx /path/to/my_files/ && chmod a=rw /path/to/my_files/*
```